# After removing and adding control it is not visible

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

In Winforms application I have form with custom control derived from `Control`. Simplified situation is the following: in the button click handler I am removing the control from `Controls` collection and adding it once again. After that it disappears - not visible. Why?

```
private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Controls.Remove(_myControl);         
    Controls.Add(_myControl);              
}
```

(In reality I want to remove this control and replace it with another control, this is a test situation.)

Comment: This now worked for me. Can you post the code that you wrote for custom control?

Comment: @user2946329 It is rather large and I am not sure what part matters for this. It is working well in a large application but has this strange bug. If you have some question, I will post a part of code

Comment: You are changing the Z-order of the control, it is now at the bottom.  So one way to not see it anymore is because it is now overlapped by another control.  A bug in the painting code would be another explanation.  Calling Remove() and not Dispose() is a gross bug that never stops causing problems.  Don't make us guess please.

Comment: Does it show if you call `_myControl.BringToFront()` after adding it?

Comment: @HansPassant Well, as I said in reality the situation is a little bit different. I have a collection of controls and when user presses next or previous on form I want to hide one of them and show another one, this is the case.

Comment: Your question does absolutely nothing to eliminate that possibility.  Please stop forcing us to guess.

Comment: I am sorry - yes, BringToFront() solved the problem. Sorry again for the trouble, you all really helped me

Comment: If bring to front worked then it's just the z-order like Hans said. Case closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that the control is indeed added to the parent form as you desire, but in a different order (ie at the end of the list) from where it had originally been inserted. As a result it may now be partially or totally hidden behind one of its sibling controls. Try adding the following after the add:

```
Controls.Add(_myControl); 
_myControl.BringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding control location before adding it again:

```
private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Controls.Remove(_myControl);    
    _myControl.Location=new Point(1,1);
    Controls.Add(_myControl);              
}
```

Comment: if _myControl was visible before the Remove, then the Location would still be valid at the time that the Add is performed